# Adding color legend to plot with colored markers

Tags: plotting

I have a plot below which plots values with extra information encoded in marker colors. What's a good pattern to add a color legend to this plot?

IE, to give user a sense what "green" means.

It's meant to plot values of $h$ (which are a function of $i$), and use $\sqrt{\exp(-h) - (1 - h)}$ for its color. Red when its large, and green when its small.

```
ClearAll["Global`*"];
h = (1 + i)^-1;
d = 1000;
DiscretePlot[h, {i, 0, d/10, 2}, PlotRange -> {h /. i -> d, 1.2},
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log", PlotStyle -> PointSize[Large], 
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y}, Hue[0.4 - (Sqrt[Exp[-y] - (1 - y)])]], 
 PlotLabel -> 
  "Approximating (1-\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(i\)]\)) with \
exp(-\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(i\)]\))", 
 AxesLabel -> {"i", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[Lambda]\), \(i\)]\)"},
 PlotLegends -> {"approx. error"}]
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

**EDIT:** Corrected error scale

Using [`Plot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Plot.html) instead of [`DiscretePlot`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DiscretePlot.html)

```
$Version

(* "13.2.1 for Mac OS X ARM (64-bit) (January 27, 2023)" *)

ClearAll["Global`*"];

h = (1 + i)^-1;
d = 1000;

{errmin, errmax} = #[{0.4 - (Sqrt[Exp[-h] - (1 - h)]), 0 <= i <= d/10}, 
    i] & /@ {MinValue, MaxValue}

(* {-0.206531, 0.39301} *)


Plot[h, {i, 0, d/10},
 ScalingFunctions -> "Log",
 PlotStyle -> Thick,
 ColorFunction -> 
  Function[{x, y}, Hue[0.4 - (Sqrt[Exp[-y] - (1 - y)])]],
 PlotLabel -> 
  "Approximating (1-\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(λ\), \(i\)]\)) with \
exp(-\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(λ\), \(i\)]\))",
 AxesLabel -> {"i", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(λ\), \(i\)]\)"},
 PlotLegends -> Placed[
   BarLegend[{Hue[0.4 - (Sqrt[Exp[-#] - (1 - #)])] &,
     {errmin, errmax}},
    LegendLabel -> "approx. error"],
   {.75, .55}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

```
error = Sqrt[Exp[-#] - (1 - #)] &;

dp = DiscretePlot[h, {i, 0, d/10, 2}, PlotRange -> {h /. i -> d, 1.2},
   ScalingFunctions -> "Log", 
   PlotStyle -> {FaceForm[], PointSize[Large]}, 
   ColorFunction -> (Hue[.4 - error@#2] &), 
   PlotLabel -> 
    "Approximating (1-\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(λ\), \(i\)]\)) with 
       exp(-\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(λ\), \(i\)]\))", 
   AxesLabel -> {"i", "\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(λ\), \(i\)]\)"}];
```

You can construct the bar legend outside `DiscretePlot` using the option `ColorFunctionScaling -> True`:

```
barlegend = BarLegend[{Hue[.4 - error @ #] &, 
   .4 - {error[h /. i -> 0], error[h /. i -> 100]}},
  ColorFunctionScaling -> True,
  LabelingFunction -> (NumberForm[.4 + First[#3, #3], {∞, 1}] &),
  LegendLabel -> Sqrt[Exp[-λ] - HoldForm[(1 - λ)]]]


Legended[dp, barlegend]
```

[image]

Add the option `ScalingFunctions -> {Log[.4 + #] &, Exp[#] - .4 &}` to `BarLegend[...]` above to get:

```
logbarlegend = BarLegend[{Hue[.4 - error @ #] &,
   .4 - {error[h /. i -> 0], error[h /. i -> 100]}}, 
   ScalingFunctions -> {Log[.4 + #] &, Exp[#] - .4 &}, 
   ColorFunctionScaling -> True, 
   LabelingFunction -> (NumberForm[.4 + First[#3, #3], {∞, 1}] &), 
   LegendLabel -> Sqrt[Exp[-λ] - HoldForm[(1 - λ)]]];

Legended[dp, logbarlegend]
```

[image]

Comment: Hm, that plot makes it look like there are some negative square roots

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov, please see the updated version.